# Gears of War 4 Split Screen Hordes?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, gears-of-war-4

I want to know if you can use a guest account on Xbox Live to add a second person to play horde with or do you need a second Xbox Live account to do this?

Answer (score 5):

[Splitscreen is supported](http://www.gamesradar.com/gears-war-4-split-screen-multiplayer-everything/) in all the coop modes for Gears of War 4 and even online.

You should not need a second Xbox Live account.  I've never seen a game do that for splitscreen.  Usually, the second player assumes the first players name with a number in parentheses next to it indicating which player they are.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can play split screen horde online with a guest account the guest player will show in game as your gamertag with a (1) after just like it was on gears 3